# Use HTML character names in jquery span text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to update the content of a span like so:

```
$('#myElement').text('&pound;' + parseFloat(myPrice));
```

But the HTML does not render the `&pound;` correctly when updated. There are other instances where I want to use a different symbol as well.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: `.html()`, use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `html()` method as `text()` encodes the value. Try this:

```
$('#myElement').html('&pound;' + parseFloat(myPrice));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
   var myPrice = "403";
   $('#price').html('&pound;' + parseFloat(myPrice));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="price"></p>
```

Comment: Can we stop wrapping every jQuery answer in `$(function(){ ... })`? This is almost never relevant and leads to people being confused whether it's actually necessary for the rest of your code to work.

Comment: Rory's answer is way less verbose yet manages to be way more informative